# include_root_in_json not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, activemodel

I've implemented `as_json` in the parent model as follows:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  options[:include] = :items
  super(options)
end
```

`include_root_in_json = true` is set in the configuration.

What I GET is:

```
[
    {
        "order": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "key1": "value1"
                },
                {
                    "key1":"value2"
                }
            ],
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }
]
```

But what I WANT is this:

```
[
    {
        "order": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "key1": "value1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "item": {
                        "key1": "value2"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    }
]
```

So the root name is not included for nested associations. Is that a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell "include_root_in_json" does not work for nested attributes but only on the very root like:

```
[
  {
    "videos": {
      "video": [
        "id": 1
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

For this example it would remove the "videos" root.

**Tip**
I found that as_json is not really good if you are building something like an API where you need to be very flexible sometimes. For that reason i am using RABL, mabye you should give it a try https://github.com/nesquena/rabl